# how to convert url to java object

Tags: java, url, converters

url:
http://www.xxx.com/getUser?userid=1&username=john&usersex=1

Java Class:

```
Class User{
     private long userId;
     private String userName;
     private int userSex;

     // get and set methods
     ...
     //constructos
     User(long userId, String userName, int userSex){
          this.userId = userId;
          this.userName = userName;
          this.userSex = userSex;
     }
}
```

how to convert this url to User object?for this url,i want to get User user = new User(1,"john",1).and does have any java framework?

Comment: I guess there is no framework which can do that, considering `userid=1` in query and `userId` field name (letter case, for other parameters as well). You should do it manually using [java.net.URL](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/net/URL.html).

Answer (score 1):

NO. just use [substring](http://www.homeandlearn.co.uk/java/substring.html) for that,and set in your object

Answer (score 0):

I think there is no java framework for this. Since solution is quite simple, you can implement it yourself.

- get attributes passed into URL via [Servlet's request parameters](http://www.exampledepot.com/egs/javax.servlet/GetReqParam.html).
- set attributes to User either dynamically using [Java Reflection API](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/reflect/index.html), or manually by implementing lots of ifelse statements

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at Apache Commons BeanUtils.

- [Java library to map request parameters onto an object](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3959785/java-library-to-map-request-parameters-onto-an-object)
- http://commons.apache.org/beanutils/

Answer (score 0):

- You can use any MVC framework like `Struts` where each HTML form will
  have a java backing bean.
- If you feel MVC is heavy, You can write    your own logic by using
  `Java Reflections API`.

Answer (score 0):

Try using Apache HttpComponents. I can help you read and parse a URL into individual components like

- Called Page
- List of Arguments with values as a Named value Pair

Link :
[Apache HttpComponents](http://hc.apache.org/)

You can use the different examples given and tweak for your purpose.

Answer (score 0):

How about using RestEasy?
I've not used it before, but based on some examples seems to be really simple. See the possible implementation:

```
@GET
@Path("getUser") //example: "/getUser?userid=1&username=john&usersex=1"
@Produces("application/json")
public User getUser(@QueryParam("userid") final long userId, @QueryParam("username") final String userName, @QueryParam("usersex") final int userSex) {
    User user = new User(userId, userName, userSex);
    // do what's required

    return user;
}
```

the question is also what output format you expect to be returned here. I provided sample for JSON reply.

Answer (score 0):

It's quite simple, no framework should be required.  See below:

public class TestClass {

```
    public static void main (String[] args) throws Exception {
        URL url = new URL("http://www.xxx.com/getUser?userid=1&username=john%20doe&usersex=1");
        String q = url.getQuery();
            User user = new User();
        for (String token : q.split("&")) {
            if (token.startsWith("userid")) {
                int index = token.indexOf('=');
                if (index >= 0 && index <token.length()-1) {
                    user.setUserId(Long.parseLong(token.substring(index+1)));
                }
            }
            if (token.startsWith("username")) {
                int index = token.indexOf('=');
                if (index >= 0 && index <token.length()-1) {
                    user.setUserName(java.net.URLDecoder.decode(token.substring(index+1)));
                }
            }
            if (token.startsWith("usersex")) {
                int index = token.indexOf('=');
                if (index >= 0 && index <token.length()-1) {
                    user.setUserSex(Integer.parseInt(token.substring(index+1)));
                }
            }
        }
            System.out.println(user.toString());
    }

}

class User {
     private long userId;
     private String userName;
     private int userSex;

     //constructos
     User(long userId, String userName, int userSex){
          this.userId = userId;
          this.userName = userName;
          this.userSex = userSex;
     }    

    User() {
          this.userId = -1;
          this.userName = "undefined";
          this.userSex = -1;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return String.format("id: %d; name: %s, sex: %d", userId, userName, userSex);
    }

    /**
     * @return the userId
     */
    public long getUserId() {
        return userId;
    }

    /**
     * @param userId the userId to set
     */
    public void setUserId(long userId) {
        this.userId = userId;
    }

    /**
     * @return the userName
     */
    public String getUserName() {
        return userName;
    }

    /**
     * @param userName the userName to set
     */
    public void setUserName(String userName) {
        this.userName = userName;
    }

    /**
     * @return the userSex
     */
    public int getUserSex() {
        return userSex;
    }

    /**
     * @param userSex the userSex to set
     */
    public void setUserSex(int userSex) {
        this.userSex = userSex;
    }
}
```

Comment: A bit myopic and verbose perhaps, but solves the problem (and nothing but the problem). There are more elegant solutions.